# SELECT where value in collection of ranges

Tags: postgresql, select, range, contains, any

I'm trying to select rows where a value is present in any of a collection of ranges.  So far, I've only been able to make the following work:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE num <@ numrange(1,4) OR num <@ numrange(7,11)
```

I was hoping I would be able to get something like

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE num <@ ANY(numrange(1,4), numrange(7,11))
```

working, but I haven't had any luck with it.

Any idea of a better solution than chaining ORs together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close... The value in the `ANY(...)` expression needs to be an array:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE num <@ ANY(ARRAY[numrange(1,4), numrange(7,11)])
```

Comment: would you happen to have any hints on indexing on the num column as well?

Comment: The `<@` operator is going to make that difficult. In that case, I'd probably just write the query as `num BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR ...`, which should have no problems using the index.